# SPLIT using " " delimiter in Google Sheets won't always preserve period following number

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, split

I'm using the `SPLIT` function to divide text around white spaces (" ") in strings. However, the output is inconsistent when a number is immediately followed by a period.

Column A below contains strings, and column B the function `=SPLIT(A1," ")` copied down:

[image]

Note how cell B1 does not contain a period after "2015". Is this a bug?

In the meantime, I'm using the following regular expression as a workaround:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.+)\s(.+)")
```

However, is there a way to account for any number of white spaces in a string?

PS: I posted this in the [Google Product Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/huzg_HKB-T4/uThZth-WpkgJ), and I'll be sure to update either thread if progress is made!

Comment: For the question `is there a way to account for any number of white spaces in a string`; Try the `*` quantifier for the `\s`, that should mean zero or more whitespaces, if it is supported.

Comment: Rather use `\s+` for space apearing one or more time

Comment: I have a feeling I'm being obtuse, but I'd need a quantifier for one or all of the capture groups, wouldn't I? `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.+)*\s(.+)")` and `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(.+)\s+(.+)")` don't replicate SPLIT's "text to columns" ability in Google Sheets. Each still only captures two parts of a string, regardless of the number of its white spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may get a little 'ugly' but see if this works:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(" "&A1:A,"^"&REPT("\s+[^\s]+",COLUMN(OFFSET(A1,,,1,6))-1)&"\s+([^\s]+)")))
```

- 6 in the offset denotes the (maximum) number of columns/groups that are outputted.
- as this is an arrayformula, no 'dragging down' is needed.

Comment: Thanks, JPV. That syntax was just what I was looking for! In my case, though, I'd swap the elegancy of the ARRAYFORMULA with the adaptability of something like this `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^"&REPT("(.+)\s",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "")))&"(.+)")` which removes the "maximum number of columns/groups" limitation.

Comment: @Greg, glad to hear you found a solution. The formula with the len() and substitute() was also my first idea, but I finally fell with the 'elegancy' of the arrayformula. Cheers, JP.